# Calculation GPS Accuracy based on known point

Tags: distance, gps, accuracy

I have 3 GPS's that were on the same point for about an hour.
Each of them yield a fairly accurate position but not a complete accurate location (obviously)

I want to know how to calculate the best GPS out of the three. The information I have is the X Y Z of the actual point, and for each GPS I have (TIME , X, Y, ACCUARCY)

What I did so far is:

- basic distance error calculation - Average of each gps and compare
- standard deviation of errors and knowlocation - compare